# How can use a variable on the other function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, variables

I am programming in ASPx and I would like to be able to use a variable that I give a value in a function and use it in another function

I created the two functions and tried to return with "Return" but it does not work

```
Public Function prova() As String
        Dim prova2 As String = "Hola"
        Return prova2
    End Function
Public Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs, prova2 As String)
        If prova2 = "Hola" Then
            Response.Redirect("Centros.aspx")
        Else
            Label6.Visible = True
        End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Turn prova() sub into a function that returns a string.  Have it return the variable prova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a `Function` and return the value:

```
Public Function prova() As String
    Dim prova As String = "Hola"
    Return prova
End Function

Protected Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    If prova() = "holaa" Then
        Response.Redirect("Centros.aspx")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Code edited. But I have the next error: BC31143: The method 'Public Sub Button5_Click (sender As Object, and As System.EventArgs, prova2 As String)' does not have a signature compatible with the delegate 'Delegate Sub EventHandler (sender As Object, and As System.EventArgs)'.

Comment: There is no need to add that variable there, because the function that you call returns it. I didn't notice it was there and I just removed it in my answer.